# does changing internal dns settings interrupt network connectivity

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns

Just a quick question. Does changing the DNS servers in the network settings on Windows server cause any interruption of network connectivity? I am pretty sure the answer is no and I have tested on my workstation. I need to change the internal dns entries from one IP to another, but wanted to confirm that it should not interrupt network activity (doesn't restart nic).

Links to sources would be appreciated. Mostly I just need to prove that this change should not cause any downtime and I am having a hard time finding the right answer on here or on the internet.

I appreciate your input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No normally this shouldn't happen. At most you might have a temporary problem resolving names as long as it takes to update to the new DNS server.